# Вывод изображения из PHP

Tags: php

Доброе время суток.

Мне не удаётся вывести изображение из php скрипта. Вот сам скрипт

```
<?php
include("mysql.php");
$res = mysql_query("SELECT ip, portik, time FROM online", $db);
if (!$res) {
    echo "Запрос на выборку не прошел. Напишите администратору:***";
    exit(mysql_error());
}
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($res);
error_reporting(0);
$connect = fsockopen($myrow["ip"], $myrow["portik"], $errno, $errstr, $myrow["time"]);
if (!$connect) {
    echo '<img src="server-on.png">';
} else {
    echo '<img src="server-off.png">';
}
fclose($connect);
?>
```

Вставляю в html код сайта `<img src="адрес на скрипт php">` пишется словом изображение и всё, а само изображение из скрипта не отображает.

Comment: @kravasuper, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: А что конкретно не получается:

    1) Выводится текст '<img src="server-on.png">'
    или
    2) Выводится текст 'server-on.png' в сурсе имейджа

Comment: 1) выводится изображение, скрипт работает, но меня интересует эта часть: Вставляю в html код сайта <img src="адрес на скрипт php"> пишется словом изображение

Comment: Если вы уточните, в каком смысле

     <img src="адрес на скрипт php"> пишется словом изображение

то, думаю, смогу вам помочь.

**P.S** что конкретно "пишется словом"?

Comment: вот как оно отображается http://petromi.com/get/623179bfc7.png

Comment: Я посмотрел, у вас просто нет этого("623179bfc7.png") изображения(отладчик Google Chrome)! Вот и все!

Comment: оно отображается так на сайте http://petromi.com/get/d60cd7d18d.png

Answer (score 2):

```
/* 
выкидываем этот кусок
if (!$connect) {
    echo '<img src="server-on.png">';
} else {
    echo '<img src="server-off.png">';
}
а вместо него:
*/
header('Content-Type: image/png');
readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/server-'.($connect?'on':'off').'png');
// вы же пытались вывести html там, где браузер ждал байткод картинки
```

Comment: чёт не робит

Comment: Путь к файлу проверьте, там должен быть абсолютный путь к картинкам

Answer (score 1):

А чего же вы ожидали?! Ваш PHP-скрипт выводит допустим `<img src="server-on.png">` тогда при использовании `<img src="адрес на скрипт php">` результат получается таким:

```
<img src="<img src="server-on.png">">
```

Чтобы всё работало сделайте одно из нижеследуещего:

1) Вместо

```
  if (!$connect) {
        echo '<img src="server-on.png">';
    } else {
        echo '<img src="server-off.png">';
    }
```

используйте:

```
if (!$connect) {
            echo 'server-on.png';
        } else {
            echo 'server-off.png';
        }
```

2)Вместо `<img src="адрес на скрипт php">` используйте `<iframe src="адрес на скрипт php"></iframe>`

3)Оставте `<img src="адрес на скрипт php">` как есть, а PHP-скриптом выводите СОДЕРЖИМОЕ ГРАФИЧЕСКОГО ФАЙЛА с соответствующими заголовками а не путь к файлу и тем более не тег  `<img src="server-on.png">`

Comment: Не так 

    <img src="<img src="server-on.png">">

Адрес получается нормальный, но браузер считает `<img src="server-on.png">` собственно картинкой, ее телом т.е.

Зы: зато это эквивалентно

    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?=base64_encode('<img src="server-on.png">')?>">